# Querying Deep Nested Elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, traversal

I am having an issue targeting deep nested div tags in vanilla javascript. what's happening is when I run a query check I seem to be getting null. Keep in mind the DOM elements are js injected from an API so I need to target the selector and add a class.

```js
var select = document.querySelector('#wrapper div div div div');
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>div to target</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you trying to select the element?

Comment: var select = document.querySelector('#wrapper div div div div');
select.classList.add('test')

Comment: That should work.

Comment: Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/kv6mpdLb/1/

Comment: Are you assigning the variable after you inject the DOM elements?

Comment: yes the var is assigned during execution, I get this error saying "Cannot read property 'classList' of null".

 var select = document.querySelector('#conveythis-wrapper div div div div');
 select.classList.add('test');

Comment: worked. had to reorder the way the script was in the document. thanks Barmar